# Java IllegalStateException when removing items on conveyor in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I am using the following codes to remove the items on conveyors at some moments in AnyLogic. But sometimes it throws an error when executed.

```
for (ConveyorPath conveyor : zweiterTeilConveyor) {
    List list = conveyor.getAgents();
    for (Object a : list) {
        Kerze k = (Kerze) a;
        conveyor.removeAgent(k);
        kToRemove.add(k);
    }
}
```

The error message:

```
Exception during discrete event execution:
Internal error: Entity 147645 at blocked Hold root.convey_FTM.conveyorEnter.?<MHLSettings>.conveyorSystems_xjal[4].asyncStationControllers_xjal[1].enterBlocker hasn't registered in it.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error: Entity 147645 at blocked Hold root.convey_FTM.conveyorEnter.?<MHLSettings>.conveyorSystems_xjal[4].asyncStationControllers_xjal[1].enterBlocker hasn't registered in it.
```

Sadly the message itself doesn't provide too much information for me and I have no clue how to fix it. I guess at the moment the agent is waiting at for the conveyor's enter port to be free. Do you have any ideas what the error is about and how to avoid it?

Comment: hard to tell what's going on from the Java perspective, you didn't add any part of the stack trace or mark in the code where this exception happens exactly.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. I only know little in Java but I believe this problem is specific with AnyLogic itself. In the console the error was linked to these lines of codes so I posted them. I just removed the Java tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to remove elements from conveyors via code. Hence the error.

Instead, use the `outRedirect` port at the bottom:

[image]

As per the [help](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/material-handling-library/convey.html#ports), this is how you can make agents leave conveyors prematurely

Comment: Thank a lot! just tried it out and it works fine. I didn't read the help page so carefully and chose the wrong way.

Comment: No worries. You should typically *never* remove agents out of flow chart blocks yourself. Either they provided this option or you need to adjust your logic